# Find generators in GF(19)

Tags: finite-groups

I have 2 questions.

Finding generators in GF(19) is similar to finding generators in GF(2^p)?

Is primitive polynomial needed to find generators for GF(19)?

Thanks a lot.

Ya Ali.

Comment: You mean a generator of the multiplicative group?

Comment: Is this the prime field of characteristic $\;19\;$ ?

Comment: Finding generators is relatively similar. In your case the multiplicative group is cyclic of order 18, so you need to exclude elements that have order a proper factor of 18. If an element does not satisfy either of the equations $x^6=1$, $x^9=1$, it is primitive (here $6$ and $9$ were gotten by dividing $18$ by all its prime factors). A primitive polynomial is not needed for a prime field. But IIRC e.g. Matlab uses one. It is IMHO a bit silly, but I guess they have a reason.

Comment: Thanks MR Lahtonen,
I still have trouble to find generators in prime field.